# freeRTOS is running only 1 task most of the time

Tags: esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

so I am having this strange problem (I guess there is something wrong with my code), I am trying to create 2 tasks on esp32 using freeRTOS, 1st task is to receive data from the Bluetooth module and put what it received in a queue, the 2nd task then reads from that queue and sends back what was originally sent by the sender (more like an echo).

the problem is that one of the 2 tasks is only running most of the time (which is `sendData()`) and the other task barely runs (I knew that by calling `Serial.println("test")` once in the `while` loop of the 1st task and again for the other task, for the function (task) `sendData()`, the `Serial.println("test")` was called infinitely when using it inside function `sendData()`, while using same line in the other function `receiveData()` , it was only called few times, and for all the times the code doesn't work as it was intended to be.

so anyone can tell me what's wrong with my code?

### main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include "constants.h"

#include "bluetooth.h"

// utility objects
Bluetooth bluetooth;  /*this is the object throught which we can control the bluetooth*/


// task handlers
TaskHandle_t xHandle_bluetoothSendData = NULL;    /*this is the task handler for the bleutooth send data task*/
TaskHandle_t xHandle_bluetoothReceiveData = NULL; /*this is the task handler for the bleutooth receive data task*/


// Queue handlers
QueueHandle_t xQueue_bluetoothSendData = NULL;    /*this is the queue used for bluetooth send data queue task*/
QueueHandle_t xQueue_bluetoothRcvData = NULL;     /*this is the queue used for bluetooth receive data queue task*/


// task queues contents structures
typedef struct
{
  char data[BLUETOOTH_MSG_SEND_LEN];
}bluetoothSendMsg_t;

typedef struct
{
  char data[BLUETOOTH_MSG_RCV_LEN];
}bluetoothRcvMsg_t;



/**
 * @brief this is the task used for sending data from esp32
*/
void sendData(void* pvParameters)
{
  /*struct for sending data*/
  bluetoothSendMsg_t *sendMessage;

  while (1)
  {
    /*get what's in the queue*/
    if(xQueue_bluetoothSendData != NULL && xQueueReceive(xQueue_bluetoothSendData, &sendMessage, (TickType_t) 0) == pdPASS)
    {
      Serial.print(sendMessage->data);  
      bluetooth.sendData(sendMessage->data);      /*sending the message received back to receiver*/ 
    }
  }
}

/**
 * @brief this is the task used for reveiving data by esp32
*/
void receiveData(void* pvParameters)
{
  /*for sending and receiving structs*/
  bluetoothRcvMsg_t receivedMsg;
  bluetoothSendMsg_t *messageTobeSend;

  while (1)
  {

    /*receiving message form the receiver from the receiver and put it in a queue to be send back*/
    strcpy(receivedMsg.data, bluetooth.getData(BLUETOOTH_MSG_RCV_LEN, 0).c_str());

    Serial.print("test");

    /*for some reason we received an empty message*/
    if(receivedMsg.data[0] != '\0')
    {
      messageTobeSend = (bluetoothSendMsg_t*) pvPortMalloc(sizeof(bluetoothSendMsg_t)); /*make a place in the heap for this new message*/
      strcpy(messageTobeSend->data, receivedMsg.data);  /*copying received message to another struct that will be send back*/
      Serial.print(messageTobeSend->data);
      xQueueSend(xQueue_bluetoothSendData, (void*) &messageTobeSend, (TickType_t) 0); // send back to the queue , non blocking if the queue is full
      receivedMsg.data[0] = '\0';
    }

  }
  
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  bluetooth.init(); /*initialization for the code*/

  /*for debugging purposes*/
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  while(!Serial);

  /*create needed queues for inter-task communication*/
  /*docs: https://www.freertos.org/a00116.html*/
  xQueue_bluetoothSendData = xQueueCreate(BLUETOOTH_SEND_DATA_QUEUE_LEN, sizeof(bluetoothSendMsg_t*));
  xQueue_bluetoothRcvData = xQueueCreate(BLUETOOTH_RCV_DATA_QUEUE_LEN, sizeof(bluetoothRcvMsg_t*));
  
  /*create needed tasks*/
  /*docs: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos_idf.html#_CPPv423xTaskCreatePinnedToCore14TaskFunction_tPCKcK22configSTACK_DEPTH_TYPEPCv11UBaseType_tPC12TaskHandle_tK10BaseType_t*/
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(sendData, "Send data to bluetooth", BLUETOOTH_STACK_SEND_DATA, nullptr, tskIDLE_PRIORITY , &xHandle_bluetoothSendData, tskNO_AFFINITY);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(receiveData, "receive dat from the bluetooth", BLUETOOTH_STACK_RCV_DATA, nullptr, tskIDLE_PRIORITY , &xHandle_bluetoothReceiveData, tskNO_AFFINITY);


} 

void loop() {
}
```

### constants.h

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H_
#define CONSTANTS_H_


// related to the bluetooth
#define BLUETOOTH_STACK_SEND_DATA       1024      // used by freeRTOS to create task for sending data
#define BLUETOOTH_MSG_SEND_LEN          5       // used by queues for sending data to the task
#define BLUETOOTH_SEND_DATA_QUEUE_LEN   10      // used by queues to create the length of the queue

#define BLUETOOTH_STACK_RCV_DATA       1024      // used by freeRTOS to create task for sending data
#define BLUETOOTH_MSG_RCV_LEN          5       // used by queues for sending data to the task
#define BLUETOOTH_RCV_DATA_QUEUE_LEN   10      // used by queues to create the length of the queue


#endif
```

### bluetooth.h

```
#ifndef BLUETOOTH_H_
#define BLUETOOTH_H_

/*library link: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial*/
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

class Bluetooth
{
private:

    /*this is object used to access bluetooth utils*/
    BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

public:

    /*this is the name of the esp32 when being searched for*/
    const String device_name = "ESP32-Carcotech";

    /*this is the Pin number for connection with ESP for legacy devices*/
    const char *pin = "1234";

    /*constructor*/
    Bluetooth();
  
    /*destructor*/
    ~Bluetooth();

    /**
     * @brief used to receive a string from the bluetooth
     * @param dataLen: is the length of the expected data to receive from the bluetooth module
     * @param timeOutMS: is the timeOut to wait for if not all data received : put 0 to wait infinitely if didn't till recevie same dataLen
    */
    String getData(int dataLen, uint32_t timeOutMS);

    /**
     * @brief used to send data over the bluetooth module
     * @param data: this is the data to send
    */
    void sendData(String data);


    /**
     * @brief this is the initialization function, for some reason putting the intialization code in the 
     * constructor results in watchdog timer to reset the esp32 over and over and over
    */
    void init();

};

#endif
```

### bluetooth.cpp

```
#include "bluetooth.h"

Bluetooth::Bluetooth()
{


}

String Bluetooth::getData(int dataLen, uint32_t timeOutMS)
{

    // this is a counter for how many data we received
    int receivedCounter = 0;

    // this is the buffer to receive in
    String data;

    // setting the timeOut
    SerialBT.setTimeout(timeOutMS);    

    // check if we should wait indefinitely or not
    if(timeOutMS == 0)
    {   

        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            if(receivedCounter == dataLen)
                break;
            
            data += (char)SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }
        
    }
    else
    {

        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            int temp = SerialBT.read();

            if(receivedCounter == dataLen || temp == -1 )
                break;
            
            data += (char)SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }

    }

    return data + "\0";
}

void Bluetooth::sendData(String data)
{
    SerialBT.write((const uint8_t *)data.c_str(), strlen(data.c_str()));
}

void Bluetooth::init()
{
    
    // initialization of the bluetooth
    SerialBT.begin(device_name);

    // telling the bluetooth to use that pin for connection
    SerialBT.setPin(pin);
}


Bluetooth::~Bluetooth()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem comes from

- the timeout being set to `0`
- a bad behavior of `Bluetooth::getData` when timeout is `0`

Reading at `xQueueReceive` documentation:

> xTicksToWait  The maximum amount of time the task should block waiting for an item to receive should the queue be empty at the time of the call. Setting xTicksToWait to 0 will cause the function to return immediately if the queue is empty. The time is defined in tick periods so the constant portTICK_PERIOD_MS should be used to convert to real time if this is required.
>
> If INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend is set to '1' then specifying the block time as **portMAX_DELAY** will cause the task to block indefinitely (without a timeout).

So if you want to wait indefinitely when passing `0` timeout (as guess from comment), I recommend to change you code to:

```
String Bluetooth::getData(int dataLen, uint32_t timeOutMS)
{
    // this is a counter for how many data we received
    int receivedCounter = 0;

    // this is the buffer to receive in
    String data;

    // check if we should wait indefinitely or not
    if(timeOutMS == 0)
    {   
        // wait forever
        SerialBT.setTimeout(portMAX_DELAY);

        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            if(receivedCounter == dataLen)
                break;
            
            data += (char)SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // setting the timeOut
        SerialBT.setTimeout(timeOutMS); 

        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            int temp = SerialBT.read();

            if(receivedCounter == dataLen || temp == -1 )
                break;
            
            data += (char)SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }

    }

    return data + "\0";
}
```

Comment: really appreciate it, it was one of 2 main reasons I discovered, the other reason is that I had to introduce some delay inside the `while` loops (suggested by some colleage) and it worked but neither him nor I know why we should introduce this delay inside the loops using `vTaskDelay()`